# Physical power connector that does not allow reversed polarity power connection

Tags: power, reverse-polarity, power-connector

I have used those XT60 power connectors to connect from my load to the battery. The battery is a forklift battery with a voltage of 48V.

I have attached the male XT60 connector to the battery pack and the female XT60 connector to the load input via two 2.5mm power cables.

I have also shown a person how to connect the male and female XT60 connectors together. I also know the XT60 is designed not to allow a reverse polarity connector.

However today I find out my system blew. Why you might ask.....

Because that person managed to somehow connect the XT60 in a reverse polarity way. This was not expected. So my question is what other connector can I use to make it completely idiot-proof.

Also, I do not want to make a reverse polarity protection circuit because I can not keep replacing that circuit and it does not solve the problem. Hence what other idiot-proof power connectors can I use to prevent a person from doing this?

Comment: Why would you have to keep replacing a reverse polarity protection circuit? A well designed circuit can protect against reverse polarity without sacrificing itself. It might be your best option as someone that manages to reverse a XT60 can probably misfit anything.

Comment: google `UPS battery connector` and look at the pictures

Comment: @Unimportant I see most reverse protection have a fuse in series to blow, hence that would need replacing. Do you have a better circuit?

Comment: @jsotola now that is more like it!

Comment: @Joey There's a popular P-FET based reverse polarity protection circuit if you google it.

Comment: @Joey one of these may be an off-the-shelf solution ... the one that has the auto polarity box in the middle ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=smart+jumper+cables&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: @jsotola I will use the Anderson connectors for now because these guys did not do anything silly with those as yet that connect the battery to the forklift. I honestly thought those connectors were custom-made until you made me aware of it. Since you were the first to mention it can you post it below so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our forklift uses a MASSIVE Anderson Powerpole connector. Much, much larger than the Powerpoles I use on RC planes.

Comment: Yes, I see that was what jsotola was talking about. This looks like its fairly idiot-proof....

Comment: But XT60 is already polarized. How did they connect it backwards? Did they wire it backwards? I don't think you're going to be able to outsmart such an idiot.

Comment: I figure they physically forced it in the incorrect way....

Comment: Abandon all hope. Nothing will stop a determined idiot.

Comment: I will see how long the Anderson connector lasts, we engineers can only try our best, thanks for an alternative. I think I might build a circuit that tazers the person the does that again...

Comment: "*Upon this hill lies Joey. Out-fooling the fool in his unwavering belief that he could outsmart the fool.*"

Answer (score 1):

You could use fully-insulated quick disconnect terminals with the battery + going to a female terminal and the battery - going to a male terminal, with the mating terminals on your load.  It doesn't stop someone from connecting the quick disconnects from the battery to each other, but if you really care about that you could replace one pair with bullet connectors or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your load, something like a Neutrik powerCon connector might work, if you need something more current than what neutrik can offer (up to 32A continuous ) then a series 5 cpc connector would work.